# Updating a Label during an ICommand Action

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, action, icommand

In WPF, using MVVM design, I've created a screen designed to load large numbers of logs into a `ListView` on the click of a button. Upon return, a label is updated to display the number of logs returned. This process can sometimes take a while. Our DA is in the process of optimizing things, but meanwhile I am required to make the following changes to indicate to the user that the search is running:

1. Display the mouse as a `WaitCursor`.
2. Update the label text to display "*Searching...*".

I have a class which implements `ICommand` and I have the `WaitCursor` working correctly. However, I cannot get the desired behavior for updating the label to display when the search is running. My current code:

**MyScreen.xaml**

```
<Button 
    Name="DisplayButton"
    Content="Display Logs"
    Command="{Binding DisplayLogsCommand}"
    Margin="0,64,10,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Width="112"/>
<Label 
    Content="{Binding LogsShowingText}"
    Margin="0,0,127,8"
    Foreground="#FF3C3B3B"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Width="145" Height="24"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
    FontSize="11"/>
```

**MyScreenVM.cs**

```
private Command displayLogsCommand;
private string logShowingText;

public Command DisplayLogsCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (this.displayLogsCommand == null)
    {
      // Attempt 3 made here.

      bool useWaitCursor = true;

      Func<bool> canExecute = () => this.ValidateFields();

      Action execute = () =>
      {
        /*
         *  TODO: Update this.LogsShowingText to read "Searching..."
         */

        // Attempt 1 and 2 made here.
        LogEntry[] entries = this.ClientConnection.GetLogs();

        this.LogsShowingText = string.Format("Showing {0} Logs", entries.Length);
        this.FilteredEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>(entries);
      };

      this.displayLogsCommand = new Command(useWaitCursor, canExecute, execute);
    }

    return this.displayLogsCommand;
  }
}

public string LogsShowingText
{
  get
  {
    return this.logsShowingText;
  }
  set
  {
    this.logsShowingText= value;
    OnPropertyChanged("LogsShowingText");
  }
}
```

Thus far the results and my associated failed attempts are below:

1. **After** logs are returned, the Label only reads "*Searching...*".

   ```
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.LogsShowingText = "Searching..."));
   ```
2. **After** logs are returned, the Label only reads "*Showing N Logs*".

   ```
   this.LogsShowingText = string.Format("Searching...");
   ```
3. **Before** and **during** search, the Label reads "*Searching...*", then **after** logs are returned, Label reads "*Showing N Logs*". Same code as #2, different location.

I understand this probably has something to do with the UI being blocked until the Action completes, which clearly explains attempt 1 showing the last queued update to the label and attempt 2 showing the last hard coded update to the label. Attempt 3 almost works, but the Label should not be updated until the user has clicked the button to perform the search. How can I do this?

Comment: What `ICommand` implementation are you using there? Is `Command` part of some framework?

Comment: @poke It's an in-house implementation inheriting directly from `ICommand`.

Comment: Okay, can you then tell us how the action is invoked? Is it just called on the current thread (`action()`) or in some other way? Also, I’m not sure how attempt 3 does not meet the requirements. The command is invoked when the button is clicked (which performs the search?), so showing the “searching” text before and during the search seems good. And when the command completes, it will show “showing N logs”. Isn’t that the correct behavior?

Comment: It's almost the correct behavior. When you first open the screen, it will read "Searching...".  That's where it's incorrect.  It should read that coinciding with when the mouse show the WaitCursor.

Comment: So the initial text, before pressing the button, is wrong? Can’t you set the property in the constructor to some other value then?

Comment: You can update INPC properties from *any thread*.  No need to marshall these calls to the UI thread.  Bindings (post 3.5.1, IIRC) will marshall INPC property updates to the UI thread for you.  OOoh, also Execute actually runs on the UI thread, so lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an expensive command, meaning the UI hangs while it processes, you should convert it to an async command.

```
public Command DisplayLogsCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (this.displayLogsCommand == null)
    {
        bool useWaitCursor = true;
        Func<bool> canExecute = () => this.ValidateFields();

        Action execute = async () =>
        {
           this.LogsShowingText = "Searching";

          // Attempt 1 and 2 made here.
          LogEntry[] entries = await Task<LogEntry[]>.Run(() => this.ClientConnection.GetLogs());

          this.LogsShowingText = string.Format("Showing {0} Logs", entries.Length);
          this.FilteredEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>(entries);
       };

      this.displayLogsCommand = new Command(useWaitCursor, canExecute, execute);
    }

    return this.displayLogsCommand;
  }
}
```

By making the `Action` delegate async, you can now await within the `Action`. This lets you wrap the call to your DataLayer in a `Task` and await it. Now that the expensive operation is running off the UI thread, your label will be updated properly before and after. No need to marshall the changes using a Dispatcher.

This will update the labels only when the command has been executed by the user clicking the button.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  It appears to search a little faster too. This does remove the WaitCursor however. How could I retain that?

Comment: I wouldn't know without seeing the implementation of your Command class.

Comment: My example still has you passing `true` in for the `useWaitCursor` constructor parameter. Set a breakpoint in your `Command` class and see what's happening inside of it that's preventing it from being set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Before I noticed the class had the constructor parameter, I was manually changing the mouse in my Action.  Doing that again still failed until I used a constructor without that parameter.

Comment: @OhBeWise if you are doing it manually, be sure you do it before the await call. Without seeing the Command class source, it's hard to trouble shoot much further than that. The async action itself wouldn't prevent you from setting the mouse. The only time you'd have an issue, is if you tried setting it within the Task itself.